# What is the significance of duplicating syntax-group name references?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

According to [`:syn-define`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-define),

> several syntax ITEMs can be put into one syntax GROUP.

Am I correct to infer that, regardless of the number of ITEM
instances, *e.g.*,

```vimscript
syn keyword alphaBeta alpha beta
syn match alphaBeta "\<α\>"
syn match alphaBeta "\<β\>"
```

the ITEMs that share a syntax-group name make a *single*
syntax group (e.g. `alphaBeta`)?

In general, syntax commands `:syn-keyword`, `:syn-match`,
`:syn-region`, and `:syn-cluster` take arguments that expect
a list of comma-separated syntax-group names and
`@clusterName` references. These arguments, at large, are
`contains`, `containedin`, `nextgroup`, `matchgroup`, `add`,
and `remove`.

Is there any significance in duplicating a syntax-group name
in *any* such arguments?

E.g.

```vimscript
syn cluster greekLetters add=alphaBeta,alphaBeta,alphaBeta
```

There are instances of such duplication in a few distributed
[syntax files](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime/syntax).

Try on a local copy:

```bash
cd repos/vim/vim/
ack --vim --max-count=1 '(\b\D\w+\b),\b\1\b' runtime/syntax/
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I honestly suspect these are typos… but best to ask the mailing list/issue tracker to be sure

Comment: Searches: `rg -t vim --pcre2 '(\b\D\w+\b),\b1\b' $vim_source/runtime/syntax/`; `git -C $vim_source grep -P '(\b\D\w+\b),\b1\b' -- 'runtime/syntax/*.vim'`; `:vimgrep /\(\<\D\w\+\>\),\<\1\>/ $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/*.vim` (takes a few seconds, so use a good `:grep` if you can)

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10458) was filed.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The search pattern for the git-grep command should reach for a backreference (\1), not a number (1) after the comma (,): `git -C $vim_source grep -P '(\b\D\w+\b),\b\1\b' -- 'runtime/syntax/*.vim'`.

Comment: Good catch; i think the backslashes just got lost

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It turns out that such reference duplicates are just noise. Would you care to write a proper answer so as to formally consummate this query?

Comment: Feel free to self-answer :) and reference the GitHub issue as appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Repeated* syntax-group names and cluster references are
*superfluous* in a particular syntax command argument; when
found, they are quietly passed over.

Read Bram Moolenaar's comment in the [discussion](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10458) held on
the subject.